# Anyone using a third-party Windows registry editor that they would recommend to others?

Tags: windows, registry

I work with the Windows registry editor (regedit.exe) on a near-daily basis, and occasionally find myself wishing it had more features.

For example, it'd be nice if it had:

- a way to import and export favorites.
- an advanced search feature that lists all the keys it found, rather than a simple Find feature. It would be great if there was a way to narrow the results as you type, but yes, I realize I'm probably asking for a lot.
- a list of keys I recently accessed (history)

So essentially, I'm just looking for a reliable third-party tool that builds upon the existing regedit feature set. I'm interested in both free and commercial solutions.

Previous developer recommendations have led me to discover great tools like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net) and [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/), so I'm really looking forward to your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the applications suggested by others, you might consider looking into learning a bit about [Windows PowerShell](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/management/powershell/default.mspx).  PowerShell's registry provider allows access to the registry with its powerful scripting language, so you might be able to script solutions for some of your common problems.

Answer (score 0):

These programs might be worth looking at:

http://resplendent-registrar.findmysoft.com/

I can't vouch for them (haven't used them), but they might meet your needs.

Comment: No one click on those links, they have a virus!!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is to your liking:
Registry Workshop
http://www.torchsoft.com/en/rw_information.html